# Catching Linux kernel events

Tags: linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel

I am new to Linux world but I have 2 years experience in android programming and about 5 years experience in .Net and C++ (Windows) .
I know in windows there is possibility to hook windows Core events and catch some events from it,, So I need to do this in Linux . As you know Android core is basically Linux and we can create some applications using Android NDK (Native development Kit) . Indeed I've searched for Text Selection BroadcastReceiver in android but I figured out there is not any possibility to do this. therefore I decide to program through NDK to catch some Event like Text selection or something like that in Linux, I have not any idea if it is possible or not ?
but I need some advise from someone who has similar experience before .

Comment: The Linux kernel is not responsible for selecting text in Android.  You probably ought to re-phrase this in terms of the problem you're trying to solve, rather than the solution you think you need (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: May be people want more inputs from ur side to understand what you want. So please be specific whats that you are doing.